# How do i increase my swap partition size in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, swap, ubuntu-14.04

I had a **2 GB RAM** before. So When i installed Ubuntu i just gave 2 GB for **Swap** partition. Now I Had increased my RAM capacity to **4 GB** . How can i increase my Swap capacity to run my OS smoothly?
Please be specific.
I use **Ubuntu 14.04 (GNOME)** along with **Windows 8.1** (Dual boot).

Comment: I see no reason to increase swap. If you fill 2GB of swap you are already in deep trouble and the system is anything but usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space). [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067) in particular details how to increase the swap partition size. The only reason you would need more swap space is if you hibernate your PC. It will run smoothly with 4 GB RAM and 2 GB swap space.